# What is wrong with my DELETE in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

My SQL query contains an equation that doesn't function. Here is what it looks like:

```
$delete = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE $timecode - time < 86400");
```

Basically I want to delete the rows that are recorded a day ago (aka 86400s). As you can guess, `$timecode` = `time()`; and the `time` column is also a time stamp.

Comment: Please tell us what happens instead.  Also, what language are you using, what database, and please explain how the time column is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Best guess is that the time column in your table is confused with the time function. Second problem: from your description, don’t you want > instead of <?

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE $timecode - t.time > 86400;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

`$delete = "DELETE FROM table WHERE (NOW()-86400) > time";`

Comment: hi again! if you add 4 spaces, or click the {} button, it'll add code formatting to that line

Comment: oh hi @colinmarc ! your following me ;) ... alright, I'll highlight code more, your keeping me from being sloppy